# How to compare and create empty columns from file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a file that looks like this:

```
id     field
1       aa
2       bb
3       cc
```

I have a dataframe with some columns from the above file. I want to use the file and `field` column, to see if my dataframe has that column, and if not create the column with empty string:

example:

Current df:

```
aa     cc
1       2
```

post logic:

```
aa   bb   cc
1          2
```

How would I do this?

do I read in the file and create a new df?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Why would you need a new dataframe?

Comment: @roganjosh I have not tried it because I dont know how to compare an existing dataframe against a file

Comment: Well, break it to its component parts. You want a list of existing columns. You want a list of columns from the file. You want to compare the two. You want to know how to make new columns that are in the file but not existing columns. It's certainly not a situation where you can't even take the first steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, read in the file and create a new dataframe.

Assuming you start with a reference dataframe `df_ref` and a "current dataframe" `df`, you can use [`pd.DataFrame.reindex`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html):

```
res = df.reindex(columns=df_ref['field'].values)

print(res)

   aa  bb  cc
0   1 NaN   2
```

Note `NaN` ("Not a Number" / null) values are different to empty strings, but *probably* what you want if you're working with numeric data.